# Javascript Looping in odd intervals

Tags: javascript

Ok so I have this problem with a loop assignment I'm working on.
I'm supposed to use a "while" loop for the first 4 loops and a "for" loop for the remaining 15 loops. The problem is the first 4 in the while loop print to the console correctly in sequence like they're supposed to.

The remaining 15 only print to the console in odd intervals IE: "5,7,9,11...."

What's wrong with my for loop?

```
var currentGen = 1;
var totalGen = 19;
var totalMW = 0;

while(currentGen <= 4){
  console.log("Generator #" + currentGen + " is on, adding 62 MW, for a total of " +         (totalMW = totalMW + 62) + " MW!");
  currentGen++;
  }

for(currentGen = 5; currentGen < 20; currentGen = currentGen + 1){
 console.log("Generator #" + currentGen + " is on, adding 62 MW, for a total of " + (totalMW = totalMW + 124) + " MW!");
  currentGen++;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, `for` loop has its own increment section. You don't have to do it again in the body of the loop

```
for(currentGen = 5; currentGen < 20; currentGen = currentGen + 1 ) { //incrementing
 console.log("Generator #" + currentGen + " is on, adding 62 MW, for a total of " + (totalMW = totalMW + 124) + " MW!");
  // currentGen++;    // Incrementing again
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You have both

```
currentGen = currentGen + 1
```

and

```
currentGen++;
```

So every iteration you are increasing by 2, not 1.  Just do the one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you should not have the currentGen++ line inside the for loop. The for loop does that variable increment part.